# How To Use IronSource Ad Banner As Widget?

Tags: flutter, ironsource

The official IronSource library for flutter gives developers the banner usage like this,

```
 final size = IronSourceBannerSize.BANNER;
 size.isAdaptive = true; // Adaptive Banner
 IronSource.loadBanner(
   size: size,
   position: IronSourceBannerPosition.Bottom,
   verticalOffset: -50,
   placementName: 'DefaultBanner',
 );
```

Static `loadBanner` is a future method that returns nothing and overlays the banner on top of the app.

It means we are not unable to use in tree hierarchy like a widget.

Is there any point that i am missing?

Comment: As it indicates this is a position widget, it must be placed inside a stack, then you choose which screens you place the scaffold or body inside a stack next to this widget. You already looked at the implementation example of this package, it should give more details there.

Comment: It just puts the banner on top of the root. This is not something like `Widget(child:Ad Banner)` My purpose is to show banners in a list per 5-6 rows